# Cannot install anything on Ubuntu 12.04 Full Disc Error

Tags: 12.04

I tried installing build-essential and I keep getting this error:

```
(Reading database ... 375528 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic_3.2.0-51.77_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic_3.2.0-51.77_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic_3.2.0-51.77_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even if I try to install anything else I still get the same error, tried searching for someone with the same problem, found some but it didn't help me fix my problem.

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mc-root   13G  4.7G  7.3G  39% /
udev                 2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                791M  256K  791M   1% /run
none                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1            228M  228M     0 100% /boot
```

Comment: Clearly your `/boot` is full, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/90219/117103) for a solution.